# Either Change or Redirect the "/login.php?action=create_account" piece in URL

Tags: php, bigcommerce

I purchased an SSL certificate through BigCommerce because I was under the impression that this would enable me to change our url for our sign up form.

This was not the case, as purchasing the SSL certificate only makes our website url continue onto the "Create an Account" page instead of the long version they give you.

Basically, I want to know if we can either change the url or have a specified URL direct to the current page.

Current URL is **https://annloren.com/login.php?action=create_account**
We want the new one OR to type in **https://annloren.com/apply** to go to that page instead.

I'm not a developer, and this is way beyond my knowledge. Thank you in advance!

Comment: SSL is not use for change urls. You need to modify your code to achieve change url

Comment: I understand if this is literally too much to ask, and I need to hire somebody instead, but is this easily achievable? I wouldn't even know where to start to do that.

Comment: You should hire someone if you didn't have much knowledge. because changing core code without knowing how to do in proper way dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible to change the URL from `/login.php?action=create_account` while using BigCommerce for your entire site. The SSL does change your URL, but it changes it from being a `temp`/internal URL that is used to access your site if the domain name goes down to a branded URL such as `annloren.com`